# Catch errors thrown higher up in the Firebase Functions process chain

Tags: firebase, error-handling, google-cloud-functions

## Context

Firebase HTTP Functions ships with pre-installed dependencies, namely `body-parser` which will parse the request body based on the provided content-type.

So that if I call a Firebase HTTP Function with an invalid payload, i.e:

```
POST http://localhost:5000/example-project/us-central1/example
content-type: application/json

{
  test
}
```

Firebase will  send a `400 Bad Request` response:

```
TTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
x-powered-by: Express
content-security-policy: default-src 'none'
x-content-type-options: nosniff
content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8
content-length: 1012
date: Tue, 10 Dec 2019 15:38:46 GMT
connection: close

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Error</title>
</head>
<body>
<pre>...</pre>
</body>
</html>
```

Before my code is being executed.

Google Cloud mention this in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/nodejs-8-runtime#using_middleware_to_handle_http_requests):

> Cloud Functions automatically reads the request body, so you will
>   always receive the body of a request independent of the content type.
>   **This means that HTTP requests should be considered to have been fully
>   read by the time your code is executed.** The nesting of ExpressJS apps
>   should be used with this caveat—specifically, middleware that expects
>   the body of a request to be unread might not behave as expected.

## Problem

Since I am building a public facing API this is problematic for several reasons:

1. it returns `text/html` which is a mess to handle on the client side, and;
2. the error response is not consistent with the internal errors handled by my code, and;
3. it is not sufficiently descriptive.

## Question

**Is there a way to handle errors that are thrown higher up in the process chain for Firebase HTTP Functions, or is this simply one of the caveats mentioned in the documentation?**

I know that by not specifying the request content-type in the request I am able to parse it and throw what error I like but that is just poor implementation.

I found that there is an `HttpsError` class in the [Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/node/firebase.functions.HttpsError.html) which seems to be the function that throws those responses. It has a `toJSON` method which gives the error response as `application/json`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cloud Functions is failing before your code is ever executed, because the client sent a value that is technically malformed.  Hence, the [HTTP 400](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/400) response.  Unfortunately, you have no way to intercept this, as the service infrastructure is bailing out before the provided callback can be invoked, and there are no callbacks for handling these sorts of errors.

Comment: Can I configure Firebase/Google Cloud Functions so that system errors are returned as JSON? If not then could I use [`HttpError`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/node/firebase.functions.HttpsError.html) or similar (I found a few others while browsing through the source code) to throw errors that behaves and looks the same so that at least I can implement consistent error handling for my API?

Comment: I'm not aware of any such configuration.